# How is the build for a msdeployment project different than a regular web application project?

Tags: msbuild

In our CI environment we build all the cs projects and then build the deployment projects. The deployment projects do an extra step of compiling the aspx & ascx files and often catch errors that would normally be caught at run time.

1) Is there a name for this step or process?
 
2) Can I get it in the regular project builds?
3) Where can I learn about the various steps of building specifically to msbuild?
Reading the logs in verbose I'd like to have a better understanding of what is actually happening.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Is there a name for this step or process?**

This additional step is the [ASP.NET Compilation Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229863%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), which compiles your aspx/ascx pages, to speed up first load times.

> **Can I get it in the regular project builds?**

Yes - the [AspNetCompiler Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164291.aspx) will do this for you.

Or you can invoke aspnet_compiler.exe directly.